# Start Pebble app from a watchapp

Tags: android, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

The Pebble Docs clearly describe how to start a watchapp on the Pebble from an Android app, but I cannot find instructions on how to start an Android app from a watchapp. Is that possible, and how?

Comment: Could you clarify your question?  It seems like you answered the question in the first sentence.  Are you looking to start an Android app from a watch app perhaps?

Comment: So, is there a way, to start an android app from a pebble watchapp?

Comment: I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible by registering a broadcast receiver for the pebble events, here's the code:

```
    <receiver android:exported="true" android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.getpebble.action.app.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.getpebble.action.app.RECEIVE_ACK"/>
            <action android:name="com.getpebble.action.app.RECEIVE_NACK"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```